# Merging objects - Is there a way to

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, vertices

I've been using blender for a few years as a hobbyist. I am by no means an expert. I wasn't really sure what to search for outside of just 'merging objects' so sorry if this is stupid.

Is there a way to like overlap a bunch of smaller objects together and merge them into a single manifold object? Ideally with vertices formed at the joints and I'd delete the bits inside. Is this feasible, or am I just dreaming? If it's not, what would be an efficient method of achieving the same thing?

Comment: Ever tried the _Boolean Modifier_? Apart from _Difference_ and _Intersect_ it has a _Union_ mode.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I rarely ever use any modifiers outside of subsurf and mirror. I just looked it up and tried it, and it crashed blender... Thank god for auto-saves. I'm using 2.92. Kinda disappointed as this sounded exactly like what I wanted.

Comment: I don't know hox complex your object(s) might be, but I very seldomly experienced Blender crashing when using the _Boolean_ modifier... and yes, this is what you want. Maybe try it again? Or with the most recent Blender version?

Comment: As @GordonBrinkmann said - that's the way to go

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I updated to latest and tried it again. Worked perfectly, thanks.